# how to add array item to td using hover append?

Tags: jquery, hover, append

When i hover over each td the hover function works but only appends the last item in the array to all td's, how can i make it display the correct car?

```
<!doctype html>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table width="250px"  border="1" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="3">
    <tr>
        <td id ="id0">car 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id ="id1">car 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id ="id2">car 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script>
var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
for (i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
    var car = cars[i]
    $( "#id"+i ).hover(function() { 
        $( this ).append( $( "<span> make is "+car+"</span>" ) );
    }, 
    function() {
        $( this ).find( "span:last" ).remove();
    }); 
} 
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Many thanks for all the splendid answers, i'm now making progress. Unfortunately i cannot vote for any of the answers because i don't have sufficient reputation, but i really appreciate all your help.

Comment: you can choice the one that was more useful for you, and check it as the correct answer, it will be appreciated by us, remember we use our little free time to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem Explanation:**

When you register the listeners for the **hover** event on each **td**, the function keep a reference to the **car** variable. After the loop finished, that variable will contain the latest array value, so when the triggers of hover event starts, they will use this latest value.

**One solution:**

One solution is to keep the **idx** of the array on the **td** elements like an extra attribute, then you can do like on next example:

```js
var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];

$(document).ready(function()
{
    for (i = 0; i < cars.length; i++)
    {
        $( "#id" + i ).hover(function()
        {
            var car = cars[Number($(this).attr("cars-idx"))];
            $(this).append($("<span> make is " + car + "</span>"));
        }, 
        function()
        {
            $(this).find("span:last").remove();
        });
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table width="250px"  border="1" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="3">
    <tr>
        <td id="id0" cars-idx="0">car 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="id1" cars-idx="1">car 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="id2" cars-idx="2">car 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

**It will work check**

```
<table width="250px"  border="1" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="3">
    <tr>
        <td id ="id0" data-id="0" class="carHover">car 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id ="id1"  data-id="1" class="carHover">car 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id ="id2"  data-id="2" class="carHover">car 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Jquery**

```
var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
$('.carHover').hover(function(){
var dynaicid= $(this).data('id');
$( this ).append( $( "<span> make is "+cars[dynaicid]+"</span>" ) );
});
$( ".carHover" ).mouseout(function() {
  $( this ).find( "span" ).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There's various ways to do this, based on ID of the td, order of the array, etc.

Personally, I'd go about it like this:

```
var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];

var i = 0;

// assign all of your values here, not ID based
$("table td").each(function(){
  $(this).append("<span> make is "+cars[i]+"</span>" );
  i++; 
});

// Hide all of them
$("table td span").hide();

// On hover, show the one you're hovering on, hide it again when you mouse 
 off
$("table td").on({
    mouseover: function() {
        $(this).find("span").stop().show();
    },

    mouseout: function() {
        $("table td span").stop().hide();
    }
})
```